# Wordpress Plugin Angular JS Sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, sorting

I'm hoping I can ask this here and any help would be appreciated.

I'm using a Wordpress Angular JS plugin with some odd sorting alphabetical sorting.

This is the main code displaying the taxonomy

```
<!-- for taxonomy  -->
                    <div ng-if="item.option =='taxonomy' && !item.parent_taxonomy">

                            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>

                            <div ng-if="item.taxonomy">

                                <div ng-show="item.viewType == 'checkbox'">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.alloption">
                                          <input type="checkbox" ng-change="grabResult( this ,formData[item.taxonomy][key], item)"  name="{{value}}" ng-model="formData[item.taxonomy][key]"  > {{value}}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <div ng-show="item.viewType == 'select'">
                                    <select class="form-control" ng-change="grabResult( this ,formData[item.taxonomy] , item)" ng-model="formData[item.taxonomy]">
                                        <option value="">Please select</option>
                                        <option value="{{key}}" ng-repeat="(key ,value) in item.alloption">{{value}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                    </div>
```

I'm needing to alphabetize the order of the li's. Is that doable?

Answer (score 0):

The `li` are being generated from the `item.alloption` object.  Objects are unordered in JS, so you'll want to convert the Object to an array first (since arrays are ordered), and then sort the array alphabetically.

The [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)  suggest using the [toArrayFilter](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter) filter for this purpose.  You can download that filter and load it after angular.js.

The adjusted code should look something like this (assuming you want to order by keys):

```
<li ng-repeat="value in item.alloption | toArray | orderBy : '$key'">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="grabResult( this ,formData[item.taxonomy][value.$key], item)"  name="{{value}}" ng-model="formData[item.taxonomy][value.$key]"  > {{value}}
</li>
```

My code might still have issues (since I haven't run it) but hopefully the linked documentation provides a starting point.